# How to Periodic Reconnect Wifi - Rasp ZeroW

Tags: wifi

Im using pi zero W as mqtt server/Broker, running StrechLite
From time to time - wifi disconnects, and reconnection is crucial.

How can it be done?

**EDIT1**

Check #1 - Wifi ON

```
guy@HomePi_MQTT:~ $ sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 status
[sudo] password for guy: 
bssid=f0:b4:29:fc:d6:c9
freq=2437
ssid=Xiaomi_D6C8
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=CCMP
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=192.168.3.200
p2p_device_address=86:7a:2d:e5:e5:15
address=b8:27:eb:cb:96:f5
uuid=d96abd77-dee8-53e2-aba8-f57f93565c37
```

Check#2

```
guy@HomePi_MQTT:~ $ systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-08-26 19:17:13 +03; 2 days ago
 Main PID: 241 (wpa_supplicant)
   CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
           └─241 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: If you are using the default setup it happens automatically!

Comment: I don’t know what you meant by default setup- but it doesn’t...

Comment: I mean using `dhcpcd` rather the many non-standard tutorials. You have provided NO information about your setup, and NO evidence that there is a problem. What does `wpa_cli -i wlan0 status` show?

Comment: @Milliways since I don’t know what to look for- I didn’t post it. If you can, please specify more about what is needed.

Comment: *Milliways* has given you a suggestion so you should follow it. Please edit your question and insert the output from the command `wpa_cli -i wlan0 status` (copy&paste). One time when connected and one time when disconnected. You may also have a look at `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` if you can find error messages.

Comment: @Ingo - added. Only cabpable to do check#1 with wifi ON ( I'm using SSH for that)